# How to watch fixed memory free using gdb because of corruption

Tags: gdb, watchpoint

I have an array of pointers which holds the interface details.
For example

```
tIfInfoStruct      *gapIfTable[16];
```

memory has been allocated for the pointer while interface creation.
For example

```
gapIfTable[14] = 0x39cc345.
```

After some sequence of operations , the value of `gapIfTable[14]` becomes `NULL(0x0)`. I want to watch, which part of the program was releasing the memory. 
Whether I could be able to track  `gapIfTable[14]` using

```
gdb> watch *0x39cc345
```

I want my program to be stopped on gdb  when the above memory address becomes `NULL`, so that I can get the back trace in Gdb to find the culprit. I am running a multi threaded program.

Please correct If my understanding is wrong.
If am wrong , please help me out with some solutions.

Comment: watch should work - gdb will use a debug register is possible, and this will do what you need. You can also try running Valgrind, which will detect writes that exceed the size of an allocated buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> gdb> watch *0x39cc345

This watches memory at location `0x39cc345`, and *not* the memory at location `&gapIfTable[14]` that becomes `NULL`.

So you probably want to use `watch *(gapIfTable+14)` instead.